# phonebook iphone webapp

Tags: iphone, web-applications

Is it possible get all phonebook of iphone with a web application??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web application run on browser and its restricted to access only client script. By client script(Javascript/JQuery) we can't access any library/API on device.

To access phone book you need to create an iPhone native app. Ones u get the data then you can send it to server either by XML or JSON request.

So the answer for your question is NO.

Comment: many thanks for reply, I undestand now.
Best regards
Samantha

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, this probably would help you

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks, but I need to get addressbook of iphone by a web application.
Is possible?

best regards

Comment: Unfortonally for security reasons as @iPhoneDev told you it's not possible,
you can imagine that if it would be possible there could be a webpage that when you enter they stole all your information :(